# How can I get the port used to make a socket connection in Python 2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, sockets

I am making a IRC Client script to learn a bit about Python, that may evolve down the road... So I can connect with out issue. But I want to get the port that the `socket` connection is using when I use `socket.connect()` .

I ask, because I want to compile with the [Auth RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1413).
So I want to be able to send,

`MYPORT, SERVPORT : USERID : Windows : Username`

*Is it possible to get the port of the socket being used for the out going connection?* 
So something like this:

```
irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
irc.connect(('irc.rizon.net', 6667))
irc.send( str( irc.getsocketused() ) + ", 6667 : USERID : Windows : Username")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [getsockname](https://docs.python.org/2/library/socket.html#socket.socket.getsockname) method on the socket, for example for IPv4;

```
>>> irc = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
>>> irc.connect(('irc.rizon.net', 6667))

>>> addr,port = irc.getsockname()

>>> port
52675 (this will be your local port)
```